# Send DMTF tones by android application during a call

Tags: android, audio, voice

I am looking into sending tones (possibly DMTF tones) from my application during a phone call. 
There were many questions about it at "stackoverflow": The answer is normally: "It is impossible" 
But: As a user, after making a call using the dialer/phone application, I can use the numeric keypad to enter tones!!! (used frequently when call is answered by  an automated service) >>> Dial tones are inserted into the call by an app at my phone

So the question is: How does the application do it? Is there a way for me to take a similar approach for sending DMTF tones/other tones by my own application?

Comment: The phone app can do it because its actually managing the voice stream.  You can't as a 3rd party because you don't have access to that stream.  If you want to replace the dialer with your own app, that's the level of complexity you'd need to support.

Comment: THe function you need is android.telecom.Call.platDtmfTone().  But the only way to get a call object is to implement the InCallService, which would basically take over telecom handling for the phone.  It's what you'd use to write an app like Skype.

Comment: Thanks. Disappointing as the need I have cannot be met.
As for skype: This is a VoIP service and with VoIP the insertion of tones is obviously possible. (With skype-out, the phone does VoIP: Interfacing the PSTN is done by a server at the cloud)